# android OptionsMenu click times

Tags: android, menu, broadcastreceiver

Can I get OptionsMenu click times,

I want to get value to use in onReceive, like this

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        SubMenu fileMenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, 7, Menu.NONE, "歌曲");    
        fileMenu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "A");  
        fileMenu.add(0, 2, Menu.NONE, "B");  
        fileMenu.add(0, 3, Menu.NONE, "C");
        fileMenu.add(0, 4, Menu.NONE, "D");
        return true;
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:

              Toast.makeText(this, "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              break;
        case 2:

              Toast.makeText(this, "B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              break;
        case 3:

              Toast.makeText(this, "C", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              break;
        case 4:
              Toast.makeText(this, "D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              break;
        default:
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter();  
intent.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(searchDevices, intent);
private BroadcastReceiver searchDevices = new BroadcastReceiver() {  
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        if(OptionsMenu click times == 2)
    {

    }
}
```

Because I just have the process only this part,

please help me understand how to solve provide advice thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bali gave a good solution for what you asked. But there is a much simpler way to get this done without using a receiver.

Make a new class that has a static container for your click number.

ie:

```
public class ParamValues{

private static int clickNums= 0;

    /**
     * @return the clickNumber
     */
    public static int getClickNums() {
        return clickNums;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the clickNumber
     */
    public static int setClickNum(int clickNum) {
        clickNums = clickNum;
    }
}
```

Then create an onClickHandler for your OptionsMenu, and inside the click handler add in somecode like.

```
int count = ParamValues.getClickNum();
count++;
ParamValues.setClickNum(count);
```

Now you could get this click count anywhere in your code. If you want to make sure it's synchronized you could just add a function to process what you want in the same onClick.

ie:

```
if(ParamValues.getClickNum() == 2)
    {
// Do whatever
    }
```

Then in you can reset the count value in here or wherever you would want to reset it by using the convenient setter in the ParamValues class.

Using the receiver you can't guarantee exactly when the code will execute.

Answer (score 0):

From the detail you have given:

You could create a datamember in your Activity, which will store the number of times, the menukey was pressed, and increase it every time its pressed:

```
private int menuPressedCount = 0;

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        menuPressedCount++;
}
```

And you can pass this to your receiver, puting it in the Intent, which the receiver will get:

```
Intent intent = ...;
intent.putExtra("menu_pressed_count", menuPressedCount);
```

And in the onReceive():

```
int pressedCount = intent.getIntExtra("menu_pressed_count", 0);
```

Tell me if this isn't what you are looking for!